# Using a RPi Zero W as a WiFi enabled USB stick

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, samba, watchdog, cache

I have an older industrial instrument running Windows CE that I would like to access data from remotely over WiFi.  The instrument saves data (10-20 kB for each test) to a USB stick, so leveraging that I am attempting to create a WiFi enabled USB stick emulator using a Raspberry Pi Zero W (Zero 2 might also work, but it uses more power and I'm not sure how much the instrument's USB port can provide).  Data can be read-only by the Windows 11 machine I am using to access the shared folder.

I followed [this tutorial](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive) and have *almost* been able to get it to work.

To test, I have connected the Pi Zero to the instrument with a USB cable (to the Pi USB data port, not the power only USB port), run the instrument, and **verified that the data was saved to the card**.

Connecting to the Pi over wifi from a Windows 11 computer I am able to see the old data files in File Explorer, but **new data files do not appear**.  Refreshing the folder doesn't show the new data either.  If I reboot the Pi Zero and reconnect the new data shows on the Windows machine. Doing some research I found that running this command also causes the new data files to appear:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I wrote a script that repeats this command every 15 seconds that worked; I was able to have have the instrument repeatedly create new data files, and they would all appear in the Windows machine file explorer.  However, I need some way to do this on boot, so the process is fully functional without the user having to enter any commands - just plug it in and go.  Furthermore, I don't fully understand what the command does and whether it's a good idea to repeat it every x seconds.

<s>Is there a way to use Watchdog to run the drop_caches command any time the mounted USB mass storage file is changed?  Or a way to run it every x seconds, auto starting on boot?</s>

I am aware this can cause file corruption but I don't think there is a better way to accomplish what we need.

Comment: please do not assume that the watchdog timer is the solution to the problem ... or even that `drop_caches` command is the solution ... please ask about the problem, not about your perceived solution to the problem

Comment: OK @jsotola I struck out that comment